# Adding multiple Case object in related list of Person Account

Tags: page-layout, related-list

I have 2 pageLayouts for Case object.

1. Case recordtype and pageLayout 1: Assessment
2. Case recordType and pageLayout 2: Recess

I want to add both the Cases in related List of PersonAccount according to their record type/pageLayout.
I am not able to add multiple Cases in the related list.

Are there any settings for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in LX You can try this awesome offering from Salesforce Labs called 'CMTD Enhanced Related List'.We can have more than 1 related list component for the same object with filter criteria.

Just make sure you go through the user guide to understand the metadata set up of 'Enhanced Related List' before setting up the component. It is important to understand how to set up data in the Enhanced Related List

[Appexchange Link](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FYDY4UAP)
[Guide Link](https://partners.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=00P3A00000n33CfUAI)